# wicked_pdf export html links as plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I got an html page with a few links. A render the page to string, and try to generate a pdf from it.

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_string,
                                    disable_internal_links: false,
                                    disable_external_links: false)
```

Unfortunately the links(hrefs) are parsed as plain text

> Link to google (google.com)

Instead I want the links to be clickable. Like the following

[Link to google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Can you try using the symbol-based notation, ie `pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html_string, :disable_internal_links => false, :disable_external_links => false)`?  Bit of a wild stab in the dark but worth a try.

Comment: Nope. Does not work with symbol-based notations.

Comment: @fiction Do you have to pass `disable_external_links` in the `pdf_from_string` method or can you set it as a configuration? Or do you even need it at all (because I read that the default for wkhtmltopdf is to enable links)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to my own question:

The problem was that the underlying tool was ignoring the 'disable_internal_links' and 'disable_external_links' options.

I needed to update wkhtmltopdf to be wkhtmltopdf with qt patch.

I used this [install script](https://gist.github.com/Zauberfisch/8773593)

```
# you will be needing git if you haven't got it yet
sudo apt-get install git-core

sudo apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev libxrender-dev
git clone git://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf.git wkhtmltopdf

sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libx11-dev libxcursor-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev

git clone git://gitorious.org/~antialize/qt/antializes-qt.git wkhtmltopdf-qt
cd wkhtmltopdf-qt
git checkout 4.8.4
QTDIR=. ./bin/syncqt
./configure -nomake "tools examples demos docs translations" -opensource -prefix ../wkqt
make -j3 && make install

cd ../wkhtmltopdf
../wkqt/bin/qmake
make && make install
```